# OpenGL batching and disabling objects

Tags: performance, opengl

I'm combining the vertex data that has the same format in a single VBO, assigning  vertex attributes based on a material that these object use and rendering them with a single `glDrawArrays()` call.

It is all working out great until I have to disable some objects (say `object1`) from being rendered at runtime. Is this even possible, assuming I've already set up all the vertex attributes and stuff? Would it be better not to use batching at all, and have vbo/vao per object (then, if an object's disabled, just don't call `glDraw*()` on it) ?

Answer (score 0):

Batching requires putting all of your data in one buffer, but batching is not *limited* to that. Batching is about reducing the number of draw calls. Putting your data in one buffer is *necessary* for that, but not sufficient.

Putting all of your vertex data in one buffer *alone* has performance advantages, relative to having to switch buffers and vertex formats. You don't need to go all the way to batching everything into a single draw call to improve performance over using a buffer for each individual object.

In OpenGL, [as discussed in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-bCeNzgiJ8I), the primary cost of multiple draw calls isn't the draw call itself. It's the state changes you usually do *between* draw calls.

You've put your vertex data in the same buffer, and you must have managed to eliminate stage changes between objects if you could render everything with one draw call. At that point, you've already gained most of the performance you're going to. Accept that and move on to other lower-hanging fruit.